# How to view the bind mounts for a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-container

How do I see what the bind mounts are for a given container? Something like `docker volume ls`, but for bind mounts.

Answer (score 1):

`docker inspect NAME|ID`

e.g.,
`docker inspect my_container_id`

This will give a lot of low-level information about the container, including the bind mounts.  Search the output for `Mounts`.

Examples:

```
$ docker inspect my_container_name
...
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/Users/my_user/my_dir_to_mount",
        "Destination": "/my_mount",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    },
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Name": "vscode",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/vscode/_data",
        "Destination": "/vscode",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "z",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
],
...
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/Users/my_user/my_dir_to_mount",
            "Target": "/my_mount",
            "Consistency": "cached"
        },
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Source": "vscode",
            "Target": "/vscode"
        }
],
```

Converted to [gron](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron) format (gron = "grep-able JSON"):

```
$ docker inspect my_container_name | gron | grep Mounts
json[0].HostConfig.Mounts = [];
json[0].HostConfig.Mounts[0] = {};
json[0].HostConfig.Mounts[0].Consistency = "cached";
json[0].HostConfig.Mounts[0].Source = "/Users/my_user/my_dir_to_mount";
json[0].HostConfig.Mounts[0].Target = "/my_mount";
json[0].HostConfig.Mounts[0].Type = "bind";
json[0].HostConfig.Mounts[1] = {};
json[0].HostConfig.Mounts[1].Source = "vscode";
json[0].HostConfig.Mounts[1].Target = "/vscode";
json[0].HostConfig.Mounts[1].Type = "volume";
json[0].Mounts = [];
json[0].Mounts[0] = {};
json[0].Mounts[0].Destination = "/my_mount";
json[0].Mounts[0].Mode = "";
json[0].Mounts[0].Propagation = "rprivate";
json[0].Mounts[0].RW = true;
json[0].Mounts[0].Source = "/Users/my_user/my_dir_to_mount";
json[0].Mounts[0].Type = "bind";
json[0].Mounts[1] = {};
json[0].Mounts[1].Destination = "/vscode";
json[0].Mounts[1].Driver = "local";
json[0].Mounts[1].Mode = "z";
json[0].Mounts[1].Name = "vscode";
json[0].Mounts[1].Propagation = "";
json[0].Mounts[1].RW = true;
json[0].Mounts[1].Source = "/var/lib/docker/volumes/vscode/_data";
json[0].Mounts[1].Type = "volume";
```